# Queryselector returns null, can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Im trying to select a button, but it keeps returning null.
I've used just this exact method before, but now it only returns null.. 
I tried using "document.GetElementById" but that resulted in the same thing.
Hope someone can help me understand why this isn't working properly!

Here is my code:

html(index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Oppgaver kap 11 - Itslearning</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="todimArray.js"></script>
    <button id="knapp">Trykk her</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript(todimArray.js):

```
var poeng = [
    [12, 15, 15, 13],
    [16, 13, 14, 13],
    [17, 18, 17, 17],
    [9, 10, 7, 11],
    [12, 15, 19, 16],
    [12, 12, 17, 10],
    [19, 18, 20, 18],
    [16, 12, 17, 16]
];

var knapp = document.querySelector('#knapp');
var bodyEl = document.querySelector('body');
var pEl = document.createElement("p");

knapp.addEventListener('click', oppgA);

function oppgA() {
    var elevNr = Number(prompt("Skriv inn eleven sitt nummer:"));
    var setning = "";
    var sum = 0;
    var gjennomsnitt = 0;

    if (elevNr > 0 && elevNr < poeng.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < poeng[elevNr - 1].length; i++) {
            sum += poeng[elevNr - 1][i];
        }
        gjennomsnitt = sum / poeng[elevNr - 1].length;

        setning = "Eleven sin poeng sum er " + sum + ". Gjennomsnittet er " + gjennomsnitt;
    }
    else{
      setning = "Tallet du skrev inn er ugyldig!";
    }
    p.innerHTML = setning;
    body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: Either move script below `<button>` element or make it run on DOMReady event. The way it goes now, the element is not yet in DOM when the script looks for it.

Comment: typos - `p` and `body` used instead of `pEl` and `bodyEl`...

Comment: As mentioned, script is loaded before the element is loaded on the page, best practice (unless there is a need to load the script earlier) is to load your JS files at the bottom after all your content, this ensures any references are already loaded

Comment: Apart from the mentioned typos you can change your script tag to read like `<script type="text/javascript" src="todimArray.js" defer></script>` Also see the [defer](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try moving your script tag to the the end of the body like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Oppgaver kap 11 - Itslearning</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="knapp">Trykk her</button>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="todimArray.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

like this your script loaded after the entire DOM Elements finish to load (in your case the knapp button)

2) you have wrong variables name :

change

```
p.innerHTML = setning;
body.appendChild(p);
```

to

```
pEl.innerHTML = setning;
bodyEl.appendChild(pEl);
```

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion work perfectly, thanks : -)

Answer (score 1):

You should mark your HTML like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Oppgaver kap 11 - Itslearning</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="knapp">Trykk her</button>

    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="todimArray.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You should always link your JS files before the closing body tag if possible, because the script is not aware of the button if you link the script before the button.

You can also use the event `DOMContentLoaded` in pure javascript or `$(document).ready()` in jquery if you need to link your script before your HTML